# caffe|Message type "caffe.ParamSpec" has no field named "propagate_down"

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, caffe

I want to fix some layers's parameter while training so I use `propagate_down:0` in a layer like this:

```
  layer {
  name: "conv5_2"
  type: "Eltwise"
  bottom: "conv5_1"
  bottom: "conv5_2_1x1_increase"
  top: "conv5_2"
  param{
    propagate_down：0
  }
  eltwise_param {
    operation: SUM
  }
}
```

I want to fix parameters before this layer and only finetune parameters after this layer.

but I meet the error:

```
I0316 15:08:21.036813 20524 solver.cpp:81] Creating training net from train_net file: /home/muses/WSnet/C_coarse2fine/config/pspnet101_ele_8s_train.prototxt
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/text_format.cc:274] Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 6595:19: Interpreting non ascii codepoint 239.
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/text_format.cc:274] Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 6595:19: Message type "caffe.ParamSpec" has no field named "propagate_down".
F0316 15:08:21.039957 20524 upgrade_proto.cpp:88] Check failed: ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param) Failed to parse NetParameter file: /home/muses/WSnet/C_coarse2fine/config/pspnet101_ele_8s_train.prototxt
```

how to solve this please?

Comment: Usually, when I need to fix the weights of some layers, instead of using `propagate_down`, I set the `lr_mult: 0` on those layers. This multiply the learning rate of that particular layer with 0, which means the weights won't be updated at all. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

The parameter [`propagate_down`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L347-L354) is used to indicate whether to backprop gradients to layer's inputs or not. It is **not** meant to indicate whether to update a *parameter* or not.
To fix a parameter in caffe you need to set `param { lr_mult: 0 }` for that specific parameter.